# Word-count job hangs in Hadoop: compiled, submitted, accepted and never terminates

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-ec2, freeze

Having successfully configured a Hadoop cluster on AWS EC2, at least to the point where issuing the `jps` command on the each type of node elicits the following output:

```
6544 ResourceManager
4305 JobHistoryServer
7004 Jps
6252 NameNode
```

Similarly:

```
2753 NodeManager
2614 DataNode
3051 Jps
```

Following the standard Apache tutorial for creating a WordCount programme I've completed all the prerequisite steps, compiled the Java class as well as the `.jar`, as [described here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html).

However, when I execute the programme with the following command:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar wc.jar WordCount /user/wordcount /user/output2
```

The job just hangs with the following output on my console:

[image]

The management web-interface displays the following information:

[image]

Perhaps it's something related to my `yarn`?

In creating this environment I largely followed this [tutorial](https://dwbi.org/etl/bigdata/183-setup-hadoop-clusterStep).

Here is how I've arranged my configuration files:

`yarn-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>128</value>
        <description>Minimum limit of memory to allocate to each container request at the Resource Manager.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>2048</value>
        <description>Maximum limit of memory to allocate to each container request at the Resource Manager.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores</name>
        <value>1</value>
        <description>The minimum allocation for every container request at the RM, in terms of virtual CPU cores. Requests lower than this won't take effect, and the specified value will get allocated the minimum.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
        <value>2</value>
        <description>The maximum allocation for every container request at the RM, in terms of virtual CPU cores. Requests higher than this won't take effect, and will get capped to this value.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
        <value>4096</value>
        <description>Physical memory, in MB, to be made available to running containers</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
        <value>4</value>
        <description>Number of CPU cores that can be allocated for containers.</description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

`mapred-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
    <value>master:10020</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
    <value>master:19888</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.staging-dir</name>
    <value>/user/app</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

`hdfs-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>  
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_work/hdfs/namenode</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_work/hdfs/datanode</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir</name>
    <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_work/hdfs/namesecondary</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.secondary.http.address</name>
    <value>172.31.46.85:50090</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

`core-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://master:8020/</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://master:9000/</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/tmp</value>
    <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Perhaps it's important to see how my `~/.bashrc` is configured, apart from boilerplate, it looks like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib:${PATH}
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar

# export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
# adding support for jre
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/*:.

#trying to get datanode to work :/
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop

export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom"
```

Comment: check something in logs !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you delete all the folders in here:

```
/usr/local/hadoop_work/hdfs/namenode/
/usr/local/hadoop_work/hdfs/datanode
/usr/local/hadoop_work/hdfs/namesecondary
```

Usually just have to do something along the lines of `rm -rf current/`.

Configured accordingly:

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
     <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
     <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
     <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>master</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Turns out that setting `yarn.resourcemanager.hostname` is pretty important, that was tripping me up for a while :/

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
     <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
     <value>hdfs://master:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
     <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
     <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.replication</name>
     <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
     <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_work/hdfs/namenode</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir</name>
    <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_work/hdfs/namesecondary</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
     <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_work/hdfs/datanode</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.secondary.http.address</name>
    <value>172.31.46.85:50090</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
666.13.46.70  master
666.13.35.80  slave1
666.13.43.131 slave2
```

Essentially, you wanna be looking at this:

[image]

Execute the commands...

Very simple tutorial:

```
hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-*.jar wordcount /input /output
```

For this [example](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html):

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar wc.jar WordCount /input /output
```